# How to set the value of dr7 register in order to create a hardware breakpoint on x86-64?

Tags: c, linux, x86-64, breakpoints, ptrace

I'm working on a "binding" library that allows to use `ptrace()` in the OCaml language but my question only relates to `ptrace()`.

So, right now, I'm trying to write a small piece of code in order to create a simple hardware breakpoint on Linux x86-64 by using `ptrace()`:

```
#define DR_OFFSET(x) (((struct user *)0)->u_debugreg + x)

typedef struct {
    int           dr0_local:    1;
    int           dr0_global:   1;
    int           dr1_local:    1;
    int           dr1_global:   1;
    int           dr2_local:    1;
    int           dr2_global:   1;
    int           dr3_local:    1;
    int           dr3_global:   1;
    int           reserverd:    8;
    break_flag_t  dr0_break:    2;
    data_length_t dr0_len:      2;
    break_flag_t  dr1_break:    2;
    data_length_t dr1_len:      2;
    break_flag_t  dr2_break:    2;
    data_length_t dr2_len:      2;
    break_flag_t  dr3_break:    2;
    data_length_t dr3_len:      2;
} dr7_t;

CAMLprim value ptrace_breakpoint(value ml_pid, value ml_addr)
{
    CAMLparam2(ml_pid, ml_addr);
    dr7_t dr7 = {0};

    dr7.dr0_local = 1;
    dr7.dr0_break = 0; /* break on execution */
    dr7.dr0_len   = 0x03; /* len 4 */

    ptrace(PTRACE_POKEUSER, Int_val(ml_pid), DR_OFFSET(0), (void*)Int64_val(ml_addr));
    ptrace(PTRACE_POKEUSER, Int_val(ml_pid), DR_OFFSET(7), (void*)dr7));
    ptrace(PTRACE_POKEUSER, Int_val(ml_pid), DR_OFFSET(6), (void*)0);
    CAMLreturn0;
}
```

When I execute this code, I got an `Invalid argument`. The value of `dr7` is `0xc0001`. In order to find a valid value, I inspected how GDB use `ptrace` by using `strace`:

```
ptrace(PTRACE_POKEUSER, 6459, offsetof(struct user, u_debugreg), 0x400519) = 0
ptrace(PTRACE_POKEUSER, 6459, offsetof(struct user, u_debugreg) + 56, 0x101) = 0
ptrace(PTRACE_POKEUSER, 6459, offsetof(struct user, u_debugreg) + 48, 0) = 0
```

So, GDB set the dr7 register to the value `0x101`. I tried this value and it works. Thus, I'm wondering what is the meaning of the value used by GDB? Is the `dr7_t` bit fields that I used before valid?

Thank you.

**Edit:**

Thanks to Neitsa, here is the solution:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned int  dr0_local:      1;  
    unsigned int  dr0_global:     1;  
    unsigned int  dr1_local:      1;  
    unsigned int  dr1_global:     1;  
    unsigned int  dr2_local:      1;  
    unsigned int  dr2_global:     1;  
    unsigned int  dr3_local:      1;  
    unsigned int  dr3_global:     1;  
    unsigned int  le:             1;  
    unsigned int  ge:             1;  
    unsigned int  reserved_10:    1;  
    unsigned int  rtm:            1;  
    unsigned int  reserved_12:    1;  
    unsigned int  gd:             1;  
    unsigned int  reserved_14_15: 2;
    break_flag_t  dr0_break:      2;  
    data_length_t dr0_len:        2;  
    break_flag_t  dr1_break:      2;  
    data_length_t dr1_len:        2;  
    break_flag_t  dr2_break:      2;  
    data_length_t dr2_len:        2;  
    break_flag_t  dr3_break:      2;  
    data_length_t dr3_len:        2;  
} dr7_t;

CAMLprim value ptrace_breakpoint(value ml_pid, value ml_addr)
{
    CAMLparam2(ml_pid, ml_addr);
    dr7_t dr7 = {0};

    dr7.dr0_local = 1;
    dr7.le = 1;
    dr7.ge = 1;
    dr7.reserved_10 = 1;

    my_ptrace(PTRACE_POKEUSER, Int_val(ml_pid), DR_OFFSET(0), (void*)Int64_val(ml_addr));
    my_ptrace(PTRACE_POKEUSER, Int_val(ml_pid), DR_OFFSET(7), (void*)dr7));
    my_ptrace(PTRACE_POKEUSER, Int_val(ml_pid), DR_OFFSET(6), (void*)0);
    CAMLreturn0;
}
```

Comment: Signed int bitfields? You're brave.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your structure looks good (I would have used `unsigned int` though).

[image: DR7 bits]

A few remarks (quotes are from `Intel Manual chap 17.2: Debug Registers`):

- Reserved bits (**must** be set accordingly to the documentation):

  - Bit 10 is reserved but set to 1.
  - Bits 12, 14 and 15 are reserved and must be set to 0 (`memset` the whole structure to 0 beforehand).

Other fields:

- You **should** also implement bit 8 and bit 9 and set them to 1

> LE and GE (local and global exact breakpoint enable) flags (bits 8, 9)
> — This feature is not supported in the P6 family processors, later
> IA-32 processors, and Intel 64 processors. [...] , **we recommend that
> the LE and GE flags be set to 1 if exact breakpoints are required**

- Instruction breakpoint for instructions **must** have length set to 1 byte (which implies that the corresponding `LENn` field must be set to 0):

> Instruction breakpoint addresses must have a length specification of 1
> byte (**the LENn field is set to 00**). Code breakpoints for other operand sizes are undefined

So, to set a breakpoint on execution:

- Set the reserved bits to their right values
- Set DR7.LE and DR7.GE to 1
- Set DR7.L0 (L1, L2, L3) to **1** [local breakpoint]
- Make sure DR7.RW/0 (RW/1, RW/2, RW/3) is **0** [break on instruction exec]
- Make sure DR7.LEN0 (LEN1, LEN2, LEN3) is **0** [1 byte length]
- Set DR0 (1, 2, 3) to the instruction linear address

  - The linear address of the breakpoint [DR0 to DR3] **must** fall on the first byte of the instruction.

> The processor recognizes an instruction breakpoint address **only when
> it points to the first byte of an instruction**. If the instruction has
> prefixes, the breakpoint address must point to the first prefix.

---

**edit**

- 0x101 :

  - bin(0x101) = '0b100000001'
  - DR7.L0 & DR7.LE set to 1

Technically, 0x701 should be correct:

- 0x701 :

  - bin(0x701) = '0b11100000001'
  - DR7.L0 & DR7.LE & DR7.GE & DR7.bit10 set to 1

Comment: It's just perfect. Thanks a lot for these informations. I updated `dr7_t` and filled it according to your recommandations. It works well!